# c - tcp - netmap : could tun/tap interface neglict the use of netmap?

Tags: c, tcp, packet

I just asked a question here : [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327439/c-tcp-stack-where-to-start-to-learn-how-to-implement-it?noredirect=1#comment41322179_26327439)

Would a Tun/tap device avoid a netmap/pf_ring/dpdk installation ?
If tun/tap allow to bypass kernel, isn't it the same thing ?

Or those codes bring so many optimizations that they overclass tun os bypass strategy ?

I don't quite understand here.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TUN/TAP interfaces are virtual network interfaces in which instead of sending and receiving packets from physical media, sends and receives them from user space program. They don't by pass kernel but it's common to set TAP interface as the default interface in order to have a user space program to intercept applications traffic.

Consider below diagram a typical interaction of an userspace program with network interface and network stack.

```
+--------------------------+                                               
| Network Interface Driver |                                               
+------------+-------------+                                               
             |                                                             
+------------+-------------+                                               
|      Network Stack       |                                               
+--------+---+---+---------+                                               
         |   |   |           Kernel Space                                  
+----------------------------------------+                                 
         |   |   |           User Space                                    
         |Sockets|                                                         
         |   |   |                                                         
+--------+---+---+---------+                                               
| User Space Applications  |                                               
+--------------------------+
```

There’s no way to entirely bypass network stack in case of TAP interface. Userspace applications can still connect to physical interface. Only if a frame specifically is directed to the TAP interface the interceptor application can intercept frames.

```
+--------------------------+     +--------------------------+              
| Network Interface Driver |     |       TAP Interface      |              
+------------+-------------+     +--------+----+------------+              
             |                            |    |                           
+------------+-------------+              |    |                           
|      Network Stack       +--------------+    |                           
+---+------------------+---+                   |                           
    |                  |                       |              Kernel Space 
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |                  |                       |              User Space   
Sockets to NIC    Sockets to TAP       TAP File Descriptor                 
    |                  |                       |                           
+---+------------------+---+     +-------------+------------+              
|    Normal Applications   |     | Interceptor Application  |              
+--------------------------+     +--------------------------+
```

In case of Netmap once userspace application exclusively acquired the NIC it is up to userspace application to decide which frames (if any) can be injected to the network stack. Therefore we can have the performance of direct packet capturing and take advantage of network stack services when we need them. The exclusive access to NIC is not a good feature always, consider the simple scenario when the NIC has to reply to ARP request.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+              
|          Netmap Enabled Network Interface Driver          |              
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------+              
      |                                                                    
+-----+-----+ +-----------+      +--------------------------+              
| NIC Rings | | Host Ring +------+     Network Stack        |              
+-----+-----+ +-----+-----+      +--------+---+---+---------+              
      |             |                     |   |   |           Kernel Space 
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      |             |                     |   |   |           User Space   
 MMAP Access   MMAP Access                |Sockets|                        
      |             |                     |   |   |                        
+-----+-------------+------+     +--------+---+---+---------+              
| Interceptor Application  |     |    Normal Applications   |              
+--------------------------+     +--------------------------+
```

Unfortunatly DPDK doesn’t support “host rings” according to http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/sample_app_ug/netmap_compatibility.html

I’m not certain about PF_RING

Also note in order to utilize NETMAP/PF_RING/DPDK you must modify, recompile or even redesign your application to match to the frameworks.

Comment: Thanks Amir ! i ended up to the same conclusion and rewrote a full blown tcp stack. Even faster than the alternatives I mentioned :D

Comment: Wow, full blown tcp stack, it's going to be a big project.

Comment: it is already done :) And yes, lot of c lines and assembly. But works very fine :) People will benefit from it without even knowing about it. I don't care fame.

Comment: If it's open source project would you let me know the name on the web site of project?